# C# FileHelpers Nulls in Tab Delimited file

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm parsing a tab delimited file using FileHelpers.

The null values are being ignored after using the `FieldNullValue` attribute and I am ending up with the error log

> can't be found after the field 'filed name' at line 4 (the record has less fields, the delimiter is wrong or the next field must be marked as optional).

Class definition of delimiter:

```
[DelimitedRecord("\t")]
```

Fields are all strings with the same attributes:

```
 [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
 [FieldNullValue("NULL")]
 [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForRead, MultilineMode.AllowForRead)]
 public String initials;
```

Looking at the imported file in a hex editor i can see back to back tab chars (09 09) which would I assume be a null field.

[image: file line in hex view]

As you can see in the screen capture fields 5 & 9 are null.  These get ignored by the filehelper parser.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why are the null values not being replaced by the FieldNullValue attribute instead of throwing errors about the number of fields

Comment: do you mean changing the input format? if so then its not an option.  I am considering the route of editing the file programmatically first to replace all double tabs to a blank string but didn't really wan tot go down that route.

Comment: Does your model allow nullable fields for field5 & 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the attribute:

```
[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
```

Seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I was just about to write this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two problems going on.

Firstly, FileHelpers is expecting one more tab. One easy fix is to mark the last field with the `[FieldOptional]` attribute.

Secondly, `FieldNullValue("NULL")` means: If the value of the field in the file is `null`, set it to the string "NULL". The value in your file is `""`, not `null`. If you need to convert empty values to something else, you can use [a custom converter](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_customconv.html) as follows:

```
public class MyEmptyFieldConverter : ConverterBase
{
    protected override bool CustomNullHandling
    {
        /// you need to tell the converter not 
        /// to handle empty values automatically
        get { return true; } 
    }

    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(from))
            return "NULL";
        return from;
    }
}
```

And then add the attribute to your field.

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(MyEmptyFieldConverter))]
public string field9;
```